# generate id label from cell label excel formula

Tags: excel, formula

I don't know how to make formule to automatic generate id for position in table
I cant't use in this file VBA - only formula

Count All position with argument "BOX"
and add to LABEL POSITION

- 1.1
- 1.2
- 1.3
- 1.4
- 1.5
- 2.1
- 2.2
- 3.1
- 4.1 etc...

Efect (make manual - image)

http://srv3.sendfile.pl/pobierz/951704---nb9y/5316677400_1326980696.jpg

Any sugestion how to make this ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with formulas. For example, if box ids are in E column, put this formula into cell F1 and fill down:

```
="RQ-CLO-"&E1&"."&COUNTIF($E$1:E1,E1)
```

Comment: your formuls is bad, excel not understend this, after edit range result is: "RQ-CLO-1.9" where 9 is all counted label

Comment: check my example file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2x_I7I1nAg1bkJTek1pYmYzelU

Comment: All is okay, my mistake!

Thanks !